# Android 11 - access file in private storage

Tags: android, android-11

Access to private storage should be possible. So I did a simple test for a test app. I will migrate all my other decent apps later.

I put a file from my desktop to <phone>/Android/data/nl.xyz.myapp/files/example.json.

Just made a quick test to access the data:

```
File file = new File(MainActivity.mainActivity.getFilesDir(), "example.json");
```

Reading from the file gave an empty string. Ohw?

When listing the files using the getFilesDir() I saw that only a .Fabric file was there. I couldn't remember putting a file like that over there ;-)

How to make this simple test succeed by reading the data from the file in the private storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is trying to read from [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). Your location is on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Start by replacing your code with:

```java
File file = new File(MainActivity.mainActivity.getExternalFilesDir(null), "example.json");
```

Once you have that working, get rid of the static `mainActivity` field in `MainActivity`, so you get rid of your memory leak.

Comment: Tx, after this quick test will do decent steps to do the real migrations.